# Javascript Executes function onload but not firing onclick event for button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hi there I have just learning the javascript query event handler function and for some reason the javascript executes on load even though i have imported the javascript just before ending the body tag

**also for some reason the onclick event is not firing could some one please tell me why! thank you!**

```js
var starter=0;
var type;

var addstarter=document.querySelector("#addstarter");
addstarter.addEventListener("click",calculate("addstarter"));

var minusstarter=document.querySelector("#minusstarter");
minusstarter.addEventListener("click",calculate("minusstarter"));

function calculate(type)
{   
  switch(type)
  {
    case'addstarter': starter=starter+1;
    break;

    case 'minusstarter':starter=starter-1;
    break;
    }
    alert(starter);
}
```

```css
#Starter
{
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  height:40%;
  background-color:rgb(55, 128, 85);
  color: white;
  margin: 5% 1% 1% 4%;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
}

#Starter img
{
  width:50%;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="Starter">
      
     <div class="card_border">
        <div class="card_heading">
         <p> Starter Pack </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card_content">
        <input type="button" value="+" class=" button button1" id="addstarter"/>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entr%C3%A9e"><img src="images/starterr.png"></a>
        <input type="button" value="-" class=" button button2" id="minusstarter"/>
        <span class="tooltiptext">$5</span>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace:

`addstarter.addEventListener("click", calculate("addstarter"));`

to:

`addstarter.addEventListener("click", () => calculate("addstarter"));`

[Cause it should be a callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
var starter=0;
var type;

var addstarter=document.querySelector("#addstarter");
addstarter.addEventListener("click", () => calculate("addstarter"));

var minusstarter=document.querySelector("#minusstarter");
minusstarter.addEventListener("click", () => calculate("minusstarter"));

function calculate(type)
{   
  switch(type)
  {
    case'addstarter': starter=starter+1;
    break;

    case 'minusstarter':starter=starter-1;
    break;
    }
    alert(starter);
}
```

```css
#Starter
{
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  height:40%;
  background-color:rgb(55, 128, 85);
  color: white;
  margin: 5% 1% 1% 4%;
  padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10% 10% 10% 10%;
}

#Starter img
{
  width:50%;
  margin-top: -5%;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div id="Starter">
      
     <div class="card_border">
        <div class="card_heading">
         <p> Starter Pack </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card_content">
        <input type="button" value="+" class=" button button1" id="addstarter"/>
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entr%C3%A9e"><img src="images/starterr.png"></a>
        <input type="button" value="-" class=" button button2" id="minusstarter"/>
        <span class="tooltiptext">$5</span>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Answers cannot consist of code only. Add an explanantion of what you did and why.

Comment: I know it, I edited my answer, please upvote..